# Facebook App request not sending

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facebook-ios-sdk

I am following the Hackbook Sample Code by Facebook to send app request to my friends in iOS. When I use the app Id generated by Hackbook, it is working fine in my app. However, when I use my app Id then it is not working. Am I missing something at the time of generating the App id?  Please suggest.

Comment: Did you change the App Id in the .plist file?

Comment: Thanx for the response. I think I solved the problem.At the time of creating app Id in Native ios block section I used the bundle Id like:"com.xxxxxx.yyyyy"  but I was not using "iPhone App Store ID".  I used that app id in my app.When I checked my Facebook Id today then I had got the response but quite late.Then I tried an old app "iPhone App Store ID" then I found that it is going smoothly in seconds.  My question is that do we need "iPhone App Store ID" for requests and if not then why it sent the response so late when I used it without "iPhone App Store ID" yesterday?